# I need a imaginary wall for my "game"

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm from Germany so may some words will be variables in German.

So anyway, I'm trying to make a 2d room with array (without graphics or something like that) and I got a "player" who can walk with the buttons 1, 2, 3, 4 (down right up left). here is my sourecode:

```
package f_ArrayUebungen;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class a_Array1 {

public static void main(String[] args)

{

    Scanner eingabe = new Scanner(System.in); 

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int eingeben, w = 0, s = 0, l = 0, k = 1;

    int ort[][] = new int [s][w];
    int kasten[][] = new int [][]
    { 
        //   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3
            {2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2},// 0
            {2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,2},// 1
            {2,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,2},// 2
            {2,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2},// 3
            {2,1,1,0,2,1,0,1,2,1,1,0,2},// 4
            {2,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,2},// 5
            {2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2},// 6
            {2,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,2},// 7
            {2,0,1,1,2,1,0,1,2,1,1,0,2},// 8
            {2,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2},// 9
            {2,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,2},// 10
            {2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,2},// 11
            {2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2} // 12
    };


      System.out.println("Wo satrten?\n1.)breite");
       w = sc.nextInt();
       System.out.println("2.) tiefe");
       s = sc.nextInt();

       kasten [s][w] = 3;

       for (int i = 0; i < kasten.length; i++ )
        {

          for (int j = 0; j < kasten[i].length; j++ )

              if ( kasten[i][j] == 2 ){
                  System.out.print("|");}

              else if ( kasten[i][j] == 1 ){
                  System.out.print("-");}

              else if (  kasten[i][j] == 0){
                System.out.print(" ");}

              else if ( kasten[i][j] == 3 ){
                  System.out.print("°");}
              System.out.println();     
        }

      while (k > l)
      {
          kasten [s][w] = 0;


      System.out.print("Welche Richtung? ");
      System.out.println("Runter = 1 | Rechts = 2 | Hoch = 3 | Links = 4");
      eingeben = eingabe.nextInt();
      int i=0,j=0;
      {
       if (eingeben == 1){
           s = s + 1;
       kasten [s][w] = 3;}
       if (eingeben == 2){
           w = w + 1;
           kasten [s][w] = 3;}
       if (eingeben == 3){
           s = s - 1;
           kasten [s][w] = 3;}
       if (eingeben == 4){
           w = w - 1;
           kasten [s][w] = 3;}

      }
      {
          if (kasten [s][w] == 0)
              System.out.println("nein");
      }


       kasten [s][w] = 3;

       for (int a = 0; a < kasten.length; a++ )
        {

          for (int q = 0; q < kasten[a].length; q++ )

              if ( kasten[a][q] == 2 ){
                  System.out.print("|");}

              else if ( kasten[a][q] == 1 ){
                  System.out.print("-");}

              else if (  kasten[a][q] == 0){
                System.out.print(" ");}

              else if ( kasten[a][q] == 3 ){
                  System.out.print("°");}
              System.out.println();  


        }
  }

}
```

}

so I want that the number 1 and 2 are walls. if I try to go trough them, the programm should stop me and tell me its not gonna work and i get a new decision which way I want. I hope you understood me. I know the programm could be written more easier, but its the easiest way I wrote it.

Thanks for the help :-)

Comment: On the spot where you check which key is pressed: `if (eingeben == 1)` etc.. you could check if the move is allowed before changing the position (your `s` and `w` variables).

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

First some things you can do to improve your code:

1. Please use English for all names in your software. Even if you think no one else will ever see it. (but since you already used german, i did too)
2. Don't duplicate code. Printing the map on screen will always work the same, they invented functions (or methods) for that. Please use them!
3. Don't print new line characters like "\n" when you don't need to. These can differ on other platforms. Please use `System.out.println()` to print those.
4. Indentation matters. You already did a decent job with this, but i noticed some things can trip me up, like the last line in the following snippet:

```java
      for (int j = 0; j < kasten[i].length; j++ )

          if ( kasten[i][j] == 2 ){
              System.out.print("|");}

          else if ( kasten[i][j] == 1 ){
              System.out.print("-");}

          else if ( kasten[i][j] == 0 ){
            System.out.print(" ");}

          else if ( kasten[i][j] == 3 ){
              System.out.print("°");}
          System.out.println();
```

With those improvements and advice from my comment earlier in mind, please look at this updated version of your code:

```java
package f_ArrayUebungen;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class a_Array1
{
    private static void kastenDrucken( int[][] kasten )
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < kasten.length; i++ )
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < kasten[i].length; j++ )
            {
                if ( kasten[i][j] == 2 )
                {
                    System.out.print("|");
                }
                else if ( kasten[i][j] == 1 )
                {
                    System.out.print("-");
                }
                else if ( kasten[i][j] == 0 )
                {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                else if ( kasten[i][j] == 3 )
                {
                    System.out.print("°");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    private static boolean bewegenMoglich( int[][] kasten, int s, int w )
    {
        if (kasten[s][w] != 0)
        {
            System.out.println("nein");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner eingabe = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int eingeben, w = 0, s = 0, l = 0, k = 1;
        int ort[][] = new int[s][w]; // ort is never used!
        int kasten[][] = new int[][]
        { 
        //   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3       <- this line skips number 10
            {2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2},// 0
            {2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,2},// 1
            {2,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,2},// 2
            {2,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2},// 3
            {2,1,1,0,2,1,0,1,2,1,1,0,2},// 4
            {2,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,2},// 5
            {2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2},// 6
            {2,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,2},// 7
            {2,0,1,1,2,1,0,1,2,1,1,0,2},// 8
            {2,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2},// 9
            {2,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,2},// 10
            {2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,2},// 11
            {2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2} // 12
        };

        System.out.println("Wo satrten?");
        System.out.println("1.)breite");
        w = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("2.) tiefe");
        s = sc.nextInt();

        kasten[s][w] = 3;

        kastenDrucken( kasten );

        while (k > l) // Note: k and l are never updated, so this is always true!
        {
            System.out.print("Welche Richtung? ");
            System.out.println("Runter = 1 | Rechts = 2 | Hoch = 3 | Links = 4");

            eingeben = eingabe.nextInt();
            int i=0,j=0;

            if (eingeben == 1 && bewegenMoglich(kasten, s + 1, w))
            {
                kasten[s][w] = 0;
                s = s + 1;
                kasten[s][w] = 3;
            }
            if (eingeben == 2 && bewegenMoglich(kasten, s, w + 1))
            {
                kasten[s][w] = 0;
                w = w + 1;
                kasten[s][w] = 3;
            }
            if (eingeben == 3 && bewegenMoglich(kasten, s - 1, w))
            {
                kasten[s][w] = 0;
                s = s - 1;
                kasten[s][w] = 3;
            }
            if (eingeben == 4 && bewegenMoglich(kasten, s, w - 1))
            {
                kasten[s][w] = 0;
                w = w - 1;
                kasten[s][w] = 3;
            }

            kastenDrucken( kasten );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you going to tell someone that they need to name their software in English? There's absolutely no need to name it in English.

Comment: @Deximus I agree on a functional standpoint. My point should be that giving variables and functions a clear and descriptive name helps others (and your self later) understand what they are for just by reading the name. It being English is more like a tip for future development, see http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/116242/how-to-name-parts-of-your-program-as-a-non-native-english-speaker

Comment: "and your self later" - If he's German, writing variables in English won't help him, writing them in German will.

Comment: I'm just trying to give a aspiring programmer some pointer that are just good practice. Not trying to start or win some online debate about what rules everyone must apply to. As with everything, there are cases where using English is just impractical (as mentioned in the topic i linked earlier). I still think one should use English while naming things in programming. Feel free to convince me otherwise.

Comment: The comments section is not for debates; so stop trying to start one.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I appreciate that :-)